# Criar uma pergunta para apresentar uma resposta, esta correto?

Tags: debate

A forma como foi criado esta pergunta: [Progress-bar para DOWNLOAD de arquivos em Jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134079/17658)

Foge dos padrões do site, pelo que eu entendo, é comum criar uma pergunta e caso ninguém consiga responder o próprio AP pode ir lá e responde-la.
Agora o próprio AP criar uma pergunta respondida, esta correto?

Comment: Até onde sei, não está correto. Deve-se orientar o OP(percebi que é novo no site) a separar pergunta e resposta em seus devidos campos.

Comment: Só está certo se ele criar um par pergunta + resposta.

Comment: Por que você removeu a sua resposta, @jbueno? Ela está certíssima. Claro, você poderia mencionar nela o que mencionou no comentário aqui: que é preciso separar o conteúdo em um par pergunta + resposta (para ficar no formato do site). Mas eu também concordo que é uma ideia fantástica permitir que um autor possa, ele/ela mesmo, já responder. O objetivo do site é criar conteúdo útil, não importa a origem. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Vou editar e restaurá-la ***=)***

Comment: Escolha sua duplicata: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/422/101, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37/101, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4791/101, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5063/101, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/410/101, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115/101, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11/101

Answer (score 3):

Não só está "correto" como é uma ideia muito legal. Não estou dizendo deste caso em específico, até porque nem li as publicações, mas digo num contexto geral. A intenção do site é gerar conteúdo útil (como foi citado pelo @LuizVieira).

Claro que neste caso a pergunta precisa ser modificada para um par pergunta + resposta para atender o formato do site, fora isso não tem nada de errado.

Se você prestar atenção, vais ver que ao publicar uma pergunta existe a opção

> Responder sua própria pergunta – [compartilhe seu conhecimento, estilo Q&A](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Inclusive, uma das perguntas mais bem votadas do site foi publicada desta forma, veja: [Por que devo usar apenas um "return" em cada função?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/18246)

Tem também um par de pergunta + resposta meu que foi bem aceito: [Colocar todo o conteúdo de um arquivo de texto em uma variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92567/18246)

Outros exemplos:

- [Como buscar um endereço por CEP nos Correios?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/400/18246)
- [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/18246)
- [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/18246)
- [Como -1 pode ser maior que 4?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47724/18246)
- [Por que devemos evitar retornar códigos de erro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21767/18246)
- [Qual a diferença entre URL e URI?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/18246)

Comment: Foi  como eu expliquei na pergunta,  fazer pergunta+resposta é válido fazer apenas resposta não.

Comment: Não foi bem isso que deu pra entender, de qualquer forma, isso não desqualifica a resposta. Eu afirmei e exemplifiquei o que você disse ***=)***

Comment: Gabriel, vc diz "Agora o próprio AP criar uma pergunta respondida, esta correto?"? A resposta é: sim. Se o AP sabe a resposta e acha que o conteúdo vai ser útil pra outra pessoa, está correto em fazê-lo. É importante diferenciar isso de ele não ter feito da forma correta como o site espera (pergunta+resposta). Como o colega Diego disse na segunda parte [do seu comentário](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5123/criar-uma-pergunta-para-apresentar-uma-resposta-esta-correto#comment18448_5123): cabe a nós orientarmos os APs inexperientes, sem desistimulá-los a produzir conteúdo útil.